# How to prevent Stack from creating .dump-hi files?

Tags: haskell, ghc, haskell-stack

By default, `stack build` creates a a directory of .dump-hi files in `.stack-work`.

In my program, the largest of these files takes 1.9 GB. (Its corresponding .hi files takes only 24 MB.) As far as I understand, these files are totally unnecessary, and this hasn't been helping my build performance.

So, how can I stop `stack build` from producing them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.dump-hi` files are in fact needed for Stack to perform correctly. Those files provide information on Template Haskell file dependencies, which are used for dirtiness checking in deciding whether to rebuild.

There is currently no way to disable generating these files, at least as far as I know.